# JQuery - How to add background color to div where parent div has ID

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me how I would make the Div that contains "G" below have a Green background color using JQuery. I have used Drupal to provide a class name of bsc-data and an id of t-impact to the parent div.

There will be other div's on the page that also have the class of pane-content but their parent div will have a different id.

```
<div class="panel-pane pane-token pane-node-field-impact-to-customer bsc-data" id="t-impact">

  <h2 class="pane-title"> </h2>
  <div class="pane-content">G</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is this to be dynamic? If not, then use CSS. Otherwise look at jQuery documentation for CSS. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will set the background of the div that is a direct child of `#t-impact` and has the `pane-content` class.

```
$('#t-impact > div.pane-content').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Docs for [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: the op want this  I would make the Div that contains "G" below have a Green background color

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#t-impact div').css('background-color',"green")
```

will do the magic....

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jQuery("#t-impact div).css({background-color:"#00ff00"});`
This will apply green back ground to the child div

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#t-impact > div.pane-content").css("background-color", "green");
```

You can see about the css selector.
">" means directly under the parent. So it can select the div.pane-content directly under the #t-impact even if you have another div.pane-content as a child of div.pane-content.